# What is the purpose of this function?

Tags: javascript

here is the function:

```
var M = [];
function haveComponents () {
        var a = 0;
        for (var n in this.M) a++;
        return a > 0;
    }
```

I would like to understand:

- the construct of "for(var n in this.M)"; I'm used to a regular for loop and I'm not familiar with this construct.
- how "this.M" fits into the code i.e. its purpose
- generally speaking, what this function would likely be used for.

Thanks

Comment: Reference the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop

Comment: I think you've left out some important parts of the code, you need to let us know what `this` is (e.g. what object is `haveCompoenents` being called as a method of).

Comment: Either this is some strange/bad code, or you're excluding some key parts. The `haveComepnents` appears to be a property on an object, but `M` is a variable. And `M` being an Array, it'll include enumerable inherited properties *(which may be the point)*.

Comment: You changed it so the function is no longer on an object. But you still have `var M = [];` and `this.M`. We have no idea what the relationship is between these two.

Comment: @thesystem: my apologies for the confusion.  this was originally an object but since I was not showing the entire object I rewrote it as a one off function.  Am I mistaken that putting the array var M = [] as I did makes it globally accessible and therefore have this.M make sense?

Comment: @max7: It depends on the value of `this`. It may be a reference to the global object, but that's not guaranteed. If this is just a small illustration of some other code, then I'd just get rid of `this.` so you reference `M` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be some missing code.

```
var M = [];
```

Assigns a new array to the variable `M`, which seems to be a global variable (but likely isn't, you just haven't shown enough code to properly determine the context).

```
haveComponents: function () {
```

That appears to be part of an object literal that assigns a function to a property called `haveComponents`.

```
        var a = 0;
```

Creates a local variable `a` and when the code executes, assigns it a value of `0`.

```
        for (var n in this.M) a++;
```

Creates a local variable `n` and sequentially assigns it the name of an enumerable property of whatever `this.M` references. If `this` is the global object, `M` will be the array initialised above. If not, it may or may not be something else. You haven't shown any other assignment, or what `this` has been set to.

For each enumerable property of `M` (which includes its inherited properties), `a` will be incremented by one.

```
        return a > 0;
    }
```

Returns `true` if `a` is greater than zero.

An equivalent function is:

```
haveComponents: function () {

    for (var n in this.M) {

      // this.M has at least one enumerable property
      return true;
    }

    // this.M has no enumerable properties
    return false;
}
```

or for the purists:

```
haveComponents: function () {
    var hasEnumerable = false;
    for (var n in this.M) {
        hasEnumerable = true;
        break;
    }
    return hasEnumerable;
}
```

Comment: How is your last example more "pure"? Assuming `this.M` is an Array and not extended with other garbage, `this.M.length > 0` is more "pure".

Comment: Just in terms of not returning from inside a loop and only having one return statement. A `hasOwnProperty` test might be better or not since it's not clear what the point of the original function is. Simply reading length may or may not do the job. :-/

Comment: @RobG: you are correct in that it was part of an object literal.  I corrected my original post so it is now more of a stand-alone function.  Regarding return a > 0; it actually returns 1 which I thought was due to the a++ and that it runs only once increment it from 0 to 1 ... am I correct?

Comment: It will return the result of the expression `a > 0`, which must be either `true` or `false`. However, if `true` is coerced to a Number, it returns `1` (e.g. `Number(true) === 1`). `a` will be incremented once for every enumerable property of `M`.

Answer (score 1):

- `for(var n in this.M)` this is a [for-each](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) loop, used to iterate over a set of values instead that by using conditions. It is used to iterate over properties of objects.
- the `this` keyword refer to the owner of the function (whose is the `haveComponents` function), while `M` is a property of `this`
- this function just, uselessly, counts elements in `M` to see if they are more than 0. Counting them is absolutely superfluous for this purpose though.

Comment: How do you define the "owner" of a function? Also, how do you define "instance variable"? And why do you call this "absolutely superfluous"?

Comment: Regarding your first and second question in JS this is a little bit tricky, I suggest you to read this article: http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/. Regarding being superfluous: because you don't need to count the number of elements inside a collection of values to know it is not empty, knowing that there is at least one element it enough.

Comment: I already know the answers. I was wondering if you understood it. Functions don't have owners. The `this` value is very dynamic, and can refer to some object completely detached from the function. The term "instance variable" doesn't make much sense since objects don't have variables. They have properties. The code isn't superfluous. Its purpose could be to check for inherited properties on the `M`, so even if `this.M` is an empty Array,  the `for-in` may find properties.

Comment: There is still no need to count them, a simple `Object.keys(this.M).length > 0` would be enough, wouldn't it? I any case I support the wrong terminology. I'm too used to OOP in the common sense.

Comment: If `M` is an array as implied, then a simple `this.M.length > 0` is even better.

Comment: @Jack: The `Object.keys` only counts "own" properties, not inherited ones. It's also not available in older browsers.

Comment: @tjameson: Unless the point of the method is to check for enumerable inherited properties. Those would not affect the `.length`.

Comment: @tjameson: Yes, in this case `M.length` would be enough. I guess the for-in would skip any cell which is not initialized which would provide a different behavior in a situation different from this one compared to a normal for.

Answer (score 1):

The function counts how many elements are in the M array.

- The `for in` allows you  to iterate object's enumerable properties , [note that this is different from a `for each` behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) where the iteration is over items rather tha properties. In javascript this translates into going into the prototype property names and list them as well, possibly resulting in unexpected result.

Comment: thanks for clarifying the difference between a for in and a for each loop.  I learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

The `for(var n in this.M)` iterates through all of the elements of `this.M`, successively storing them in the variable `n`.

I have no idea what `this.M` is, that depends on where your code comes from.

In general, I would say that this code returns whether `M` is empty or not (and returns `true` if it is not empty).

Comment: "this" is the global space, that's how it works with the array M.

Comment: How can it be? There's a syntax error if taken literally (the colon), so the only valid assumption is that the function is attached to some object and the full source is not disclosed. In `{ func: function() {return this.M;} }`, `this` is not the global space.

Comment: @tjameson That was my thought as well. Not that this code really makes that much sense overall. Edit: actually, it looks like the question was edited, and the colon was removed, so maybe it is global scope.

Comment: @Xymostech: my intention was to use global scope.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @max7 In that case, please reconsider. Using the global scope is evil.